# Changing to landscape in interface builder. Xcode 4 (iOS)

Tags: ios, interface-builder, landscape

I'm working on an iPad app that's going to be in landscape. But how I change so the window in interface builder is in landscape? I remember in the old Interface Builder I just needed to click on an arrow and it switched to landscape.

I'm using Xcode 4.

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the UI designer, select the top most item (the main view), select the attributes inspector on the right, then select the Landscape orientation option.

Comment: You need to first select View Controller.

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the orientation of the window. Try to change the orientation of the views in the attributes tab.

Answer (score 2):

In xCode 6.1.1 for the Landscape orientation: in Simulated Metrics tab select concrete divice size and select Orientation Landscape. See this picture:

[image]